# in function - waiting ajax to respond

Tags: javascript, ajax

in this function:

```
  function ValidateForm()
    {
        var ret = true;

        if ($("#txtName").val().trim().length == 0) { ret = false; $('#txtName').effect("highlight", {}, 1000); }
        if ($("#txtSurname").val().trim().length == 0) { ret = false; $('#txtSurname').effect("highlight", {}, 1000); }
        if ($("#txtUserName").val().trim().length == 0) { ret = false; $('#txtUserName').effect("highlight", {}, 1000); }
        else {
            var pData = {}; pData["username"] = $("#txtUserName").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'service.aspx?/isusernameexist/',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                data: pData,
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data[0].cnt > 0) {
                        ret = false; $('#txtUserName').effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I'm trying to validate form before insert new user but checking if username is free for usage taking some time and my function `ValidateForm()` returns value before ajax request finishes.

How to properly implement ajax functionality in case like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it this way. The event system in Javascript is asycnchronous, and the function will always return before the AJAX request is run, and the callback triggered.

You should find another way to do this. The function that calls `ValidateForm` must be re-written to take account of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. Think about what it does and how to make it work in the constraints.

Does it show an error to the user? If so, show that error in the callback function.

Does it invalidate the form or prevent submission? If so, store that as a global variable or a data attribute which you can look up later on submission.